# psql: could not connect to server: No route to host

Tags: postgresql, high-availability, master-slave

I know this is repeated question but I didn't found any solution

I want to Set-Up Master-Slave Replication for PostgreSQL 9.6 in Debian 9. But slave server could not connect master .

```
xx.xxx.xxx.205 = master
xx.xxx.xxx.206 = slave


    root@master:~# netstat -plntu |grep 5432
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6290/postgres
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN      6290/postgres

root@slave:~# netstat -plntu |grep 5432
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      31961/postgres
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN      31961/postgres
```

I get **error  first** when I  try to do Copy PostgreSQL Data from the MASTER to the SLAVE.

```
postgres@slave:~/9.6$ pg_basebackup -h xx.xxx.xxx.205 -D ~postgres/9.6/main/ -X stream -P
pg_basebackup: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: No route to host
        Is the server running on host "xx.xxx.xxx.205" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

After that I check the connection on postgresql.

There is **no** firewalld and ufw in my servers.

I edited **pg_hba.conf and postgresql.conf** on both server like this.

```
host     all         all        xx.xxx.xxx.205/32 md5
host     all         all        xx.xxx.xxx.206/32 md5
```

postgresql.conf

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

I can connect slave from master it work fine.

```
root@master:~# psql -h xx.xxx.xxx.206 -p 5432
Password:
```

**But I can't connect from slave to master.**

```
root@slave:~# psql -h xx.xxx.xxx.205 -p 5432
psql: could not connect to server: No route to host
        Is the server running on host "xx.xxx.xxx.205" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Please help me..

Comment: Most likely there *is* some network filtering at some point between slave and master, whether on one of the machines or WAF.  Can you ping or telnet 5432 from slave to master?

Comment: @tetech `root@slave:~# Trying xx.xxx.xxx.205...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: No route to host`
`root@master:~# Trying xx.xxx.xxx.206...
Connected to xx.xxx.xxx.206.
Escape character is '^]'.`

Comment: is that an issue of Iptables? how can I check that?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the solution,
my Iptables rules are different in Master and Slave.

```
iptables -L INPUT


iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -F INPUT 
iptables -F OUTPUT
iptables  -F FORWARD

iptables -L INPUT
```

Comment: tysm, been struggling for hours.